# How to upgrade Solr 5 version already in production on Linux (installed as a service)?

Tags: solr, solr5

What is the best way to update a Solr 5 version in [production](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production) (in other words installed as a service) on Linux? I have an already installed Solr 5.0 (via the Service Installation Script) and now need to upgrade it to Solr 5.2.1. Realizing some of the config files will need to be changed to take advantage of recent changes, after stopping the current instance, is the best way to simply run the new Solr 5.2.1 Service Installation Script or just untar the 5.2.1 solr-5.2.1.tgz to /opt or something else? Fortunately, I have a very simple set up (not SolrCloud).

Comment: After actually looking into the /opt folder it is fairly obvious I just need to untar solr into that folder and change the solr symbolic link to point to the new version. It would be good if there were some way you could easily delete your own questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Post the above comment as answer and accept it. I think its a good question and the answer cannot be found without a little digging. This can be very useful to other users who are trying to upgrade. Please note there were some changes to the solr script files. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7392

Answer (score 3):

After actually looking into the /opt folder it is fairly obvious I just need to untar solr into that folder and change the solr symbolic link to point to the new version. This should work most of the time keeping in mind that occasionally, as Jay pointed out, there could be changes to the solr files that could possibly require more than this.